# ASP.Net Web service, can it be nested?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I am creating a web service that has 150+ different functions. I would like to be able to split the web service into different categories: User, Account, and Content. Is there a way for me to do that while keeping them under the same service? I know I can create 3 different asmx services but I would like it if I could do something like `Services.User.MyFunction()` in C# and something similar in javascript ajax.

Comment: Ok, so I initially wanted these to all be under the same url so that the javascript url would all originate from the same place... But didnt want a single file with 150+ functions because its not very maintainable from the server side. So to win in both areas, i think ill create partial classes. That way i can have the functions broken up into individual files based on what they do and keep the easy 'Services.asmx/func' url notation via javascript side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can either have one huge service or many smaller services. However, you could use [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite) to allow the address `Services/User/MyFunction` execute the `Services.MyFunction()` method.

With that said, I would recommend splitting the service into multiple services.

Comment: I was thinking to rewriting too, but WSDL will be the same

Comment: Javascript doesn't care about your WSDL. And besides, you would still be able to access your service and WSDL from the original url.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do this I'm afraid.

I think your only option is to split this out into different asmx pages.  Would a WebService base class help to add certain WebMethods to each?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make json , with different results into one json result..having different classes & member data